# Character Handling and String Manipulation

Tags: c, string, character

I just started learning C.
I'm making the program below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char s1[1000];
    char s2 [1000];
 /*    void countchar (const char * const);  */
    void reverse(const char * const);
    char manipulate (char , const char);

    printf ("Enter sentence number 1:\n");
gets (s1);
printf ("\nEnter sentence number 2:\n");
gets (s2);

printf ("\nThe two sentences entered are:\n1. %s\n2. %s\n\n", s1, s2);

/*    printf ("_______________________________________\n\n");
countchar (s1, s2);     */

printf ("_______________________________________\n\n"
        "The first sentence reversed is:\n");
reverse (s1);
printf ("\n________________________________________\n");

manipulate (s1, s2);

return 0;
}

void reverse (const char * const s1Ptr)
{
    if (s1Ptr [0] == '\0')
        return;
    else /*{
           if (isupper (s1Ptr [0]))
                tolower (s1Ptr [0]);
                    else toupper (s1Ptr [0]);
*/
    reverse (&s1Ptr[1]);
    putchar (toupper (s1Ptr [0]));
}


char manipulate(char s1, const char s2)
{
printf ("10 characters of first sentence + 10 characters of second sentence:\n%s", strncat (s1, s2, 10));
}
```

The programs will read two sentences, then
count the number of characters, 
reverse the first sentence and convert all lowercase to uppercase vice versa, 
and append 10 character from second paragraph to first one.

The function manipulate to append the characters is not working. Can you fix it for me?
In the function reverse, how do I convert the case vice versa? Because I can only get it from lowercase to uppercase

The part with /* is because I don't know how to make the function. I really need help with this, please kindly point out my mistakes and help me to fix them.
Thank you.

Comment: its signature is wrong. It should be taking `char*`s, not single `char`s.

Comment: `void reverse (const char * const s1Ptr)` should not be `const` argument, because the function alters `*s1Ptr` (although commented out). This function is also recursive, is that what you intended? Note - there are library functions `strupr()` and `strlwr()` that operate on a char array (string). Why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: `char manipulate (char , const char);` --> char manipulate (char *, const char *); and `#include <string.h>"

Comment: @RedAlert in which line is it?

Comment: @WeatherVane Then what do you recommend the argument to be? and yes I intended it to be recursive. I haven't learned about strupr() and strlwr(), I want to learn to implement toupper and tolower. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @WeatherVane I can't get the function manipulate to work, the compiler said error:conflicting types for 'manipulate

Comment: Oh sorry yes, it's because you are not passing pointers, try `char manipulate(char *s1, const char *s2)` and `return s1;` because the function has a type.

Answer (score 0):

I have added comments to the code you posted:

```
void reverse (const char * const s1Ptr)  // don't define as const
{
    if (s1Ptr [0] == '\0')               // testing agaist 0 will do
        return;
    else /*{
        if (isupper (s1Ptr [0]))
            tolower (s1Ptr [0]);         // nothing done with the result
        else toupper (s1Ptr [0]);        // nothing done with the result
*/
    reverse (&s1Ptr[1]);                 // recursion? A simple loop would do
    putchar (toupper (s1Ptr [0]));       // OP: "Function will only uppercase it"
}
```

Rewrote this code using simpler way of pointing to a char. You still need to reverse one of the two strings but I will leave that to you to figure out.

```
void reverse (char * s1Ptr)              // don't define as const
{
    if (*s1Ptr == 0)                     // terminate recursion
        return;
    else {
        if (isupper (*s1Ptr))            // simpler way of writing s1Ptr[0]
             *s1Ptr = tolower (*s1Ptr);  // put result back in the string
        else *s1Ptr = toupper (*s1Ptr);  // because you manipulate it later
    }
    putchar (*s1Ptr);                    // swapped last two lines round
    reverse (s1Ptr+1);                   // simpler way of pointing to next character
}
```

"The function manipulate to append the characters is not working." Yes it is!